# ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor throws java.io.FileNotFoundException: No entry for content://media/external/audio/media

Tags: android, mediastore

I am in the process of updating my app to use the proper uri-based file IO & am having some issues with uris I get from Android's MediaStore.

Basically my app allows a user to select a song from the Media Store. I then open a read-only `AssetFileDescriptor` to that file, which I then use to read the file. It works fine for the most part; however, I am still getting a significant amount crash reports from users. It throws an exception on this line:

```
AssetFileDescriptor des = contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
```

The stack trace is as follows:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No entry for content://media/external/audio/media/[ID]
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:698)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1473)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1310)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1233)
```

I am sure the uri is valid as it is pulled directly from the MediaStore. It seems like the exception is saying that there is no file pointed to by the uri, but what is confusing is why that entry in the MediaStore exists if it is not backed by any file.

I've searched & found very little documentation related to the message `No entry for content`. (Mostly random SO questions with few helpful responses.) I'd appreciate if anyone could explain why this is happening.

If a solution is not possible, is there a way I could tell which MediaStore entries aren't backed by a file without opening them? It seems like a bad UX to even show these songs to the user if they aren't able to be opened by the app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you retrieve/get the `Uri` passed to `AssetFileDescriptor`

Comment: @HB First I query the MediaStore for the id of each item like this `contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new  String[] {MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns._ID},...)`. Then once I have the MediaStore id, I build the uri with `ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id)`.